# Show all customers who haven't bought anything in the summer months

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I have two tables "OEHR_Orders" and "OEHR_Customers".
[image]
[image]

A customer and an order have both a linked Customer_ID.
I now want to Display all the customers that haven't bought anything in the month July or August. This is my query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.CUST_LAST_NAME ||'.'||SUBSTR(C.CUST_First_Name,1,1) AS "Name"
FROM OEHR_Customers C INNER JOIN OEHR_ORDERS O
ON C.Customer_ID = O.Customer_ID
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM O.Order_Date) NOT BETWEEN '7' and '8'
```

Unfortunately this query doesn't give me the desired result.

Some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUST_LAST_NAME ||'.'||SUBSTR(CUST_First_Name,1,1) AS "Name"
FROM OEHR_Customers
WHERE Customer_Id not in (Select Customer_ID from OEHR_ORDERS
            WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Order_Date) NOT BETWEEN '7' and '8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to do this using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT C.CUST_LAST_NAME || '.' || SUBSTR(C.CUST_First_Name, 1, 1) AS "Name"
FROM OEHR_Customers C INNER JOIN
     OEHR_ORDERS O
     ON C.Customer_ID = O.Customer_ID
GROUP BY C.CUST_LAST_NAME || '.' || SUBSTR(C.CUST_First_Name, 1, 1)
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM O.Order_Date) BETWEEN 7 and 8
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

The `HAVING` clause counts the number of times that months 7 and 8 appear.  It then filters out customers who have a purchase in these months.

Your version of the query just gets customers who have a purchase not during these months.